# Graphically, what is positive semidefinite-ness?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, intuition, quadratic-forms, numerical-optimization

Suppose that we are trying to minimize a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we apply Newton's method, updating:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{n+1} = \mathbf{x}_n - [\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}_n)]^{-1} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_n).
\end{align}
If the Hessian $\nabla^2 f$ is not positive semidefinite, Newton's method may update $x$ against the gradient because
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{n+1} - \mathbf{x}_n &= - [\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}_n)]^{-1} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_n) \\
\implies \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_n)^T(\mathbf{x}_{n+1} - \mathbf{x}_n) &= - \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_n)^T[\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}_n)]^{-1} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_n)
\end{align}
could have either sign.
Is there a graphical way to interpret what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're trying to minimize, but Newton's method actually looks for a critical point (a solution of $\nabla f(x) = 0$).  A critical point $x_0$ where the 
Hessian matrix is not positive semidefinite is not a local minimum but a saddle point or a local maximum: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ for a negative eigenvalue $\lambda$ then 
$f(x_0 + t v) = f(x_0) + \lambda t^2 |v|^2/2 + O(|t|^3)$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  You're right that Newton's method will only give a local minimum (and will stop at a local maximum) since it's looking for a point where the gradient is zero.  I am still having trouble visualizing the second part of your answer.

Comment: For the purposes of visualization, it may be helpful to consider a case where the Hessian matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see it now.  Essentially, Newton's method is looking for points with zero slope, and decides for each eigenvector whether to go towards a local maximum or minimum based on the sign of the eigenvalue.  Is that right?

Comment: If you're close enough to a critical point it will go to that critical point, whether it's a local max, local min, or saddle.