# Why does the Newton-Raphson method sometimes not converge?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I'm talking about the Newton-Raphson method for finding square roots of matrices:
$$\begin{cases}
    X_{k+1} &= \frac{1}{2}\big(X_k + X_k^{-1}A\big)\\
    X_0 &= A
\end{cases}$$
as a "solution" to the equation $f(X)=X^2-A=O$.
For normal functions $f(x)=x^2-a=0$ it makes sense why sometimes the method does not converge. But I don't know how to intuitively explain or even understand why the matrix-version sometimes diverges.
For example: compared to the Denman-Beavers method, the Newton-Raphson method is pretty bad since it often does not converge.
So how do we explain these divergences?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to see what you ask:

Newton's method to solve an equation $$f(u)=0$$ is given by a minimization direction procedure to solve the problem $$\min_u\frac{1}{2}\|f(u)\|^2.$$

You can see this as the initial value problem
$$\tag{1}\frac{du}{dt}=-[Jf(u)]^{-1}u,\quad u(0)=u_0,$$ because [this implies that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395883/is-newtons-method-a-descending-algorithm/4396242#4396242)
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}\|f(u)\|^2\right)=-\|f(u)\|^2\leq 0.$$

If you use [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to solve (1) numerically, with step size equal $1$, you find [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Systems_of_equations)
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rll}J{ f}({ u}_j) { w}_j&=&- { f}({ u}_j)\\ { u}_{j+1}&=&{ u}_j+{ w}_j\end{array}\right.$$

Now, if you let $$f(X)=X^2-A,$$ where $A$ and $X$ are matrix, you find that $$J{ f}({ X}_j) { W}_j=X_jW_j+W_jX_j.$$ This is, in general, not iqual to $2X_jW_j$. But it holds if you choose $X_0=A$.

You can find details on matrix derivative seraching for "(\frac{dX^2}{dX})  matrix derivative" on SearchOnMath.

**Remark:** If you follows a decreasing direction, you can arrive at a [local minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Functions_of_more_than_one_variable) or a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20saddle%20point,local%20extremum%20of%20the%20function.) to $\frac{1}{2}\|f(u)\|^2$. And this can explain some non convergence of Newton's method to a desired root of $f(u)=0$.

On the other side, since you are doing the approximation $u_n\approx u(n)$, in which $u(t)$ is given by equation (1). You can have bad approximation, if $u_0$ is far from one root of $f(u)=0$, and "lost" the curve you intend to follows.